# Cannot read property '_avast_submit' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, sentry

We're are using Sentry for our React App and faced this issue. Don't know where exactly this issue is coming from? This variable '_avast_submit' (or related named variable) is not at all used in either frontend or backend. In the screenshot it's mentioned anonymous.

This issue had occurred for the user's who had used our React App, are from Mac and Windows OS specifically using Chrome browser.

[image: Error on Sentry]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is due to an Avast extension of browser.

Unfortunately when tracking (all) JS errors, also errors originating from browser extensions could reported to Sentry.

Mentioned in Github comments: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/9331